# jQuery scrollTop animation not working

Tags: jquery

The following code causes my page to animate weirdly. When the event is fired that triggers this function, html / body element drops down a few hundred pixels and then slowly glides to the top of the browser. I need the page to scroll to the top of the roi calculator element. Any ideas? This same code works perfectly on jsfiddle.

```
    var $roiCalculator = $(".roi-calculator");
    $(".roi-container .btn.yellow").on('click', function(){
        var offset = $roiCalculator.offset().top;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(".roi-calculator").offset().top
        }, 3000);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zepto doesn't have the ability to animate scrollTop.Since all animations are done through css3, you need to add a relatively small shim, [minified](http://jsfiddle.net/dtDmg/), or [not](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd7Es/). The developers are aware of this issue and are attempting to patch it for the next release.

```
var offset = $roiCalculator.offset().top;
// Is Zepto loaded?      
if ('__proto__' in {}) {
  $.scrollTo({
      endY: offset,
      duration: 3000,
    // If needed
    // callback: function() {
    // }
  });
// It's jQuery
} else {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset,
  }, 3000);
};
```

or better yet, abstract it...

```
function scrollTo(offset, time) {
    if ('__proto__' in {}) {
      $.scrollTo({
          endY: offset,
          duration: time,
        // If needed
        // callback: function() {
        // }
      });
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset,
      }, time);
    };
};

var offset = $roiCalculator.offset().top;
scrollTo(offset, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure all the DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $roiCalculator.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
        'scrollTop': offset
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: The code is in an event handler and doesn't get fired until a button is clicked. So I don't see where wrapping it in an IIFE would help :x

Comment: Can you post your fiddle?

Comment: Apparently the issue was that it Zepto was being included to thanks to that lovely statement that comes with foundation. And apparently the supposedly identical animate method in zepto, does not work. :D